# Why do my Wordpress comments have the wrong date?

Tags: wordpress, date, comments

Currently, every comment has the same date as the original post.

Theme functions PHP:

```
<div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
<?php comment_author_link() ?><?php _e('&nbsp;said:&nbsp;','my-theme-here');?>
<?php comment_date(__('Y.m.d','my-theme-here')) ?>&nbsp;<?php comment_time(__('H:i','my-theme-here')) ?>
</div>
```

Any thoughts? (or other code I need to paste here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the Wordpress docs, and looking at a few different themes, including the default theme, comment_time doesn't take any arguments. Try  `<?php comment_time() ?>` instead. Same with `<?php comment_date() ?>`